# How do I make pub/sub subscription development experience not terrible?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I am developing transformation steps which take input from one google pub/sub topic, and output to another.  Some of these transformations receive input every second 24/7, but others may go hours or even days before they see a quick burst of activity.  The obvious choice for the infrequent transformations is a push subscription to either a Cloud Function or a Cloud Run, to be able to benefit from being able to be shut off when not in use, and spun up only as needed, and the transformations in constant use may benefit from the autoscaling also.

My question is, how do I make developing these push transformation steps not utterly awful, when I compare it to the alternative of just writing a service that continuously polls one pub/sub topic, does the transformation, and writes to another pub/sub topic?  In the case of the polling service, I can debug the code in my IDE using the same source and destination pub/sub topics as the actual deployed code will use, with zero additional components.  On the other hand, if I write code that reaps all the production benefits of being a push target, everything ultimately has to be deployed to be truly sure of how it is going to behave, and even development and testing seems like it's going to need a lot of harness code wrapping the solution.

Others have the same problem, so surely it must have been solved already many times, but for some reason my web searches don't seem to be yielding much fruit.  Has anyone else setup a reasonable development environment for this, or is it truly as bad as I described?

Comment: I use the Pub/Sub emulator [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) and Docker containers to emulate Cloud Run. Speeds up the edit/compile/test cycle. Google also has the Functions emulator [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/functions-emulator).